# Filtering worksheet based on values in column of another worksheet

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dataset that contains ID, Department, and Sales for example.
In worksheet1, i will be filtering based on a single ID.
Is it possible for me to use the Department of that filtered person in worksheet1 as a filter in worksheet2 to show all the sales from that Department?

Heard about dynamic parameters but cant get my head around it to work

Comment: Dynamic parameters are something else.  Suppose you have a parameter which takes values of a field.  Now when the values of that field update, values of parameter also change, is a dynamic parameter.

Comment: I think filters work separately on separate sheets.  To make filters dependent on each other you can use `actions`

Comment: right, parameters dont take values from the filtered column itself. not too sure about the workings of actions